# Is there something wrong about the gravity formula?

Tags: gravity

Help needed, please. I need the input of the experts here. I have always been troubled by the formula ..F = G * m1 * m2 / r^2.. , which appears to be counter-intuitive. It should be ...F = G ( m1 + m2 ) / r^2.. I present here two examples to support my hypothesis.
A )  Comparing 4 different objects falling to Earth at a height of 100 m.
r^2 = (6371 + .01)^2 km. = 40590915 ... G = 6.67*10^-11 ...m1 = 5.972*10^24 kg
when m2 = 1 gm ,                     F = 9813338.722204
when m2 = 1 kg ,                     F = 9813338.722204
when m2 = 1 trillion kg( 12 zeroes), F = 9813338.722206
when m2 = 1 quintillion  kg ( 18 ) , F = 9813340.365429
     Here, heavier objects do fall faster, but impossible to observe or detect, even 
with our most delicate instruments. Only when m2 is overwhelmingly massive, do we begin to notice the difference.
B ) orbits of Earth and Moon around the Sun

m1 = mass of Sun = 1.989*10^30
                                                                                                                                    m2A = mass of earth = 5.972*10^24 and

m2B = moon = 7.3477*10^22....
average distance of Sun to Earth = 149.6 million km 
Since Moon orbits earth, then average distance to Sun also the same.
r^2 =( 149.6 million + radius of Sun 595500 ) ^2 = 150295500 km.
when m2 = moon , F = 5873.11734

when m2 = Earth , F = 5873. 13476

Here, both the Earth and Moon are falling towards the Sun at the practically same rate, and as such, the Sun's gravitational influence should not affect the orbit of Moon around the Earth. So we don't need to invoke the Hill Theory to explain why the moon is not pulled away from its orbit.
Please let me know where I've erred , and enlighten me , hopefully with a reply coherent to me. Thanks

Comment: In example A, the force between the Earth and the three masses is almost the same. So the *accelerations* they experience would differ by 21 orders of magnitude. I think that might have been noticed...

Comment: In your version of Newton's formula, if m2 is zero, there would still be a force between the two objects, even though one of them is massless. Would you care to explain?

Comment: @Mick whilst I don't know what OP is doing exactly, photons and other massless particles are still "attracted" to large bodies of mass

Comment: I think you're confusing mass and acceleration. Objects near the Earth's surface accelerate at roughly the same rate 9813338.722204 micrometers per second per second, but that doesn't mean the force is the same, since force is mass times acceleration.

Comment: thanks Mick , If m2 = 0 , it would mean that the gravitational influence is present regardless of whether any object is present. Further, it would mean that Newton was right when he said gravity is instantaneous

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Astronomy

Answer (score 2):

To enlarge on Rob's comment.

When $m_2 = 1 \mathrm{g},\ F = 9813338.722204$ and therefore a one gram mass would accelerate at $a =F/m = 9813338.722204/0.001 = 9813338722.204 \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$

When $m_2 = 1 1 \mathrm{kg},\ F = 9813338.722204$ and therefore a one kilogram mass would accelerate at $a =F/m = 9813338.722204/1 = 9813338.722204 \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$

In other words, different masses would accelerate at very different rates. Smaller masses would fall much faster than larger masses. As Rob says, that might have been noticed. Instead we observe that larger masses accelerate at the same rate as smaller ones, because larger masses have a larger force of gravity.

In fact, both masses accelerate at the same rate: $9.81 ms^{-2}$

You seem to be confusing "Force due to gravity (or weight)" with "acceleration due to gravity".

The basic problem with your idea is that it doesn't match even simple observations. Newton's model, however, is a very good fit to observations of gravity. Therefore your model is not just wrong, it very wrong and it is of no use.